# Insert values in two tables using CTE

Tags: postgresql, insert, clone, common-table-expression

I have two tables (table1 and table2).
The id of table2 is based on the id on table1.

When I insert into table1, I want to get the ids of the newly created rows,
and use it for table2 when I clone the rows but I can't seem to get it right.

Here is a sample that TABLE1 was successfully clone but can't clone TABLE2.
**TABLE1:**

```
 id |      date               | status |
----+-------------------------+--------+
  1 | 2019-09-05 11:51:53.692 | ACTIVE |
  2 | 2019-09-05 11:52:49.32  | ACTIVE |
 49 | 2019-09-05 11:51:53.692 | ACTIVE |
 50 | 2019-09-05 11:52:49.32  | ACTIVE |
(4 rows)
```

**TABLE2:**

```
 id | card_last_digits | card_name |   
----+------------+------------------
  1 | 4444             | card1     | 
  2 | 4444             | card2     |
(2 rows)
```

**SQL:**

```
WITH cloneInsert AS (
    INSERT INTO table1 (id, date, status)
    SELECT nextval('payment_sequence'), date, 'ACTIVE'
    FROM table1
  RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO table2 (id, card_last_digits, card_name)
SELECT **cloneInsert.id**, card_last_digits, card_name
FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close - you probably want to select from cloneinsert and insert into table2. Here's sample code that could help

```
create table test1(
id integer,
msg text
);

create table test2(
id integer,
msg text
);

insert into test1 values (1, 'msg1');
insert into test1 values (2, 'msg2');

with new_rows as (
   insert into test1 values (3, 'new message')
   returning *)
insert into test2 select id, msg
from new_rows;

> select * from test1;
 id |     msg     
----+-------------
  1 | msg1
  2 | msg2
  3 | new message
(3 rows)

> select * from test2;
 id |     msg     
----+-------------
  3 | new message
(1 row)
```

To make update on test2:

```
with cte as (
insert into test1 values (3, 'updated message')
returning *)
UPDATE test2
SET id = cte.id, msg = cte.msg
FROM cte WHERE test2.id = cte.id;
```

Comment: Hi. I get your point, but when I insert in table2, I will need the current data of table2 (to be cloned) and also using the new ids of table1. Is this possible?

Comment: @mengmeng are you looking to update existing row on table2 on some conditions?

Comment: I will duplicate the rows in table2, but the id in table2, should be the same with the newly inserted rows in table1. It’s much easier to update but past transactions depend on that so i’ll just duplicate

Comment: @mengmeng please provide sample data for table1/2 and expected output - sounds doable but hard to follow without data

Comment: I updated the description. I hope this is understandable.